# Display product variations on shop page

Tags: css, woocommerce, hover, product-variations

I want to display my product variations on the shop page upon hovering a product, enabling customers to add a product to the cart (with choosing the variation) without entering the single product page.

I've added the following code to the content-product.php, which displays the entire product variations of the single product page in the shop page.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

see this image as example:http://cormilu.com.br/cormilu-content/themes/cormilu-child/Images/example.JPG

As shown in the picture the variations appear underneath the products. I want them to appear over the product and only upon hover. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: With CSS I've been able to move it around, however I haven't figured out how to reduce the items shown. When I hide them with CSS it also hides on information on the single product page. Looking forward to hearing your ideas, this function will surely be useful for tons of ecommerce shops.

Comment: Ive tried using this: 
if (is_product_category( 'CATEGORYNAME' ) {

    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-CATEGORYNAME' );

}else{

    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

}  but it causes a system crash. replacing the "woocommerce" with wc doesnt work either. Does anybody have an idea? Thanks